# Outlook 2010 autocomplete stream ( cached contacts)

Tags: c#, autocomplete, outlook

I'm currently trying to develop an outlook plugin. As to implement a non functional requirenment I need to access outlook cached contacts which are stored in .nk2 file. I refered to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2011/06/13/programmatically-accessing-the-nickname-cache-in-outlook-2010.aspx) but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Edited (Answer):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);

        //IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete

        PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;

        byte[] got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
```

Currently I'm stuck in accessing byte array, When I accesing the array the values are different than how it's mentioned in this [post](http://stephengriffin.members.winisp.net/nk2/NK2WithBinaryExample.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Can you tell us which parts of the article you had trouble following? Did you have a look at [the new Outlook 2010 MAPI Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2011/08/26/outlook-2010-mapi-reference-has-been-updated.aspx)? Are you looking for a code sample.

Comment: mm didn't look into the new outlook 2010 MAPI reference. I'm stuck @ accessing MAPI property, PidTagRoamingBinary, of a hidden message in the Associated Contents table of the Inbox of the mail account’s delivery store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);

PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;

byte[] got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
```

use the description [here](http://stephengriffin.members.winisp.net/nk2/NK2WithBinaryExample.pdf) to access the fields in the `byte[]`. I completed the code it's working correctly. You just have to loop through each byte and check for data types when accessing .

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Can you use a object instead of a byte array (if that doesn't work, hover your mouse over the `GetProperty` during debugging and see what return type it expects). eg:

```
Dim objPropAcc As Outlook.PropertyAccessor    
Dim result As Object
objPropAcc = BindingStorageItem.PropertyAccessor
result = objPropAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062040-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8A48001E").ToString();
```

Ref: [how to get a sharepoint calendar url from outlook?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/el-GR/outlookdev/thread/0096a989-a653-4002-a143-231269f11d48)

**Old:**

Here is a Microsoft KB article [How to import .nk2 files into Outlook 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980542)

> Outlook 2007 and 2010 interact with the nickname cache, also known as
>   the “autocomplete stream.” The autocomplete stream is where Outlook
>   persists the autocomplete list, which is the list of names that
>   displays in the To, Cc, and Bcc edit boxes while a user is composing
>   an email. [This topic
>   here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625288.aspx) describes
>   how Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010 interact with the autocomplete
>   stream and also discusses the binary format of the file and the
>   recommended ways for interacting with the autocomplete stream.

Also have a look at some of the sample's over here: http://ol2010mapisamples.codeplex.com/, I *think* this codeplex project is run by the [MAPI expert Stephen Griffin](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/sgriffin).

Comment: I was reading that pdf you linked to and I couldn't see where you got the `byte[]` as the return type for the `GetProperty` method. Can you see my edit, I found a article on msdn that has some really nice code snippets that should get you over this hurdle.

Comment: mmm I'm actully casting the object returned by GetProperty method to a byte[]. I can see the returned byte[] with values inside when I debug. But when I access it byte by byte the values are different as they are discribed in the post http://stephengriffin.members.winisp.net/nk2/NK2WithBinaryExample.pdf

Comment: I completed the code from the way that I started. It works fine, I can access all the cached contacts. Just needed more comitment to access each byte and check it though loops, thanks everyone for the help :)