# Email list from Bytes

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

I want extract list all autocomplete email addresses in outlook 2016 (office 365) using C#. I am using following code:

```
    NameSpace olNS = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    MAPIFolder inboxFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);
    PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
```

Now how to extract email from bytes.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know your requirements but I'm going to leave a link to [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/) here, which you can use to parse email messages.

Comment: I want to extract autocomplete emails form outlook

Answer (score 1):

The binary format is described in the [document](https://portalvhds6gyn3khqwmgzd.blob.core.windows.net/files/NK2/NK2WithBinaryExample.pdf).

Also, you may find similar posts here:

- [Get autocomplete address list of Outlook in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516429/get-autocomplete-address-list-of-outlook-in-vba)
- [Outlook 2010 autocomplete stream ( cached contacts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770955/outlook-2010-autocomplete-stream-cached-contacts)

If using `Redemption` is an option, it exposes nicknames through the `RDOStore` / [RDOSession.Nicknames](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) collection.